# Wrong Google account picture

Tags: google-account

Some applications on my phone (e.g. Maps) show a wrong picture for my user account.
Specifically, an old picture is shown instead of last one I put on my Google+ account.
How can I fix this?

I use a LG-P692 (Gelato) phone.

Comment: It might take a while for the sync to happen, what's in your *Settings > Accounts & Sync*, is it active? Auto Sync checked? (this is on GB)

Comment: @t0mm13b: I have a widget on the launcher with a shortcut to enable and disable the synch setting. I activate it when my WiFi is on. Then actually I changed my profile picture before buying the phone (which is my 1st Android device). So it looks like a mulfunction on the Google side. That is the reason of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Google profile picture and your Google+ account CAN have different pictures. I'm sure most other Google apps probably use the Google profile picture. Make sure they are the same.

Answer (score 1):

I found the workaround using the **Google Talk** app:

- Open Google Talk;
- Click on your user profile thumbnail;
- Click on the profile picture and select *Change*;
- Browse for the picture and select it.

After a while with Sync option on, then the updated picture is shown on other apps.

Comment: The problem with this workaround is that the uneven picture gets back when the phone is restarted...